# min height of the background size

Tags: css

How can I set the minimum height of the background-size?
I have a background image on the css and I gave it `background-size:100%` but when I resize the browser to lower width I would like the height to stop at some point

```
.wrapper { width: 90%; margin:0 auto; } 
.slider { 
    background-image:url(image.jpg);
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:200px;  
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/

Comment: Try set `max-height`.

Comment: @AlexChar That won't help, because of `background-size: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/7/

Comment: background-size:cover; will solve your issue.

Answer (score 6):

Try `background-size:cover;` in your code instad of 100%

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/6/)**

CSS:

```
.slider {
    background-image:url(http://derailed.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shutterstock_120154516-2000x700.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:200px;
}
```

**EDIT :** **Updated** **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/13/)**

CSS:

```
.slider {
    background-image:url(http://derailed.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shutterstock_120154516-2000x700.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   min-height:200px;  
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.slider:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
```

Comment: But how can I control the max-height? or the default height?

Comment: Updated my ans according to your need

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/itaymer/t8tLg9sz/1/

https://jsfiddle.net/itaymer/t8tLg9sz/1/embedded/result/

```
.wrapper { width: 90%; margin:0 auto; } 
.slider { 
    overflow:hidden;   
}
.slider:before {
    content:'a';
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100px;
    width:100%;
    min-width:100px;
    background-image:url(http://derailed.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shutterstock_120154516-2000x700.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by your `background-size: 100%` rule.

You should look at using [CSS3 `background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) alternatives. In particular, look at `cover`:

```
.slider { 
    background-image: url(http://derailed.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shutterstock_120154516-2000x700.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/5/)

Comment: background-size: contain is similar to background-size:100%; The min-height property will not work. example: http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/11/

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3yonr0wa/11/)**

```
.slider { 
    background-image:url(http://derailed.progressionstudios.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/shutterstock_120154516-2000x700.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    min-height:200px;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

To set min-height to background-image. You must set the `background-size: cover`;

if you use `background-size: contain` this will be like `background-size:100%;` so avoid using it.

Comment: But how can I control the max-height? or the default height?

Comment: max-height will not work. But you can set height to it. In that case you may need to use media queries to make it responsive